# Superfish sub-menus extend beyond screen edges

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

This has been asked before, but I can only find fixes/hacks for deprecated versions of [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/).

If you shrink the screen, you can see that the nested/child lists are rendered off-screen.  Is it possible to fix this shortcoming so that child menus display to the left instead of the right, or recognise the screen edge in some fashion?

[image]

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/

Answer (score 0):

The nested ul-elements are positioned with ' position: absolute; ', perhaps you can think of a way to make them work with ' position: relative; '.

But where would you expect them to show up? It would be strange if it suddenly moved to the left side....

Best solutions:
On smaller screens, use another kind of menu.

Comment: I did wonder whether, rather than appear edge-to-edge, the sub-menus might be able to overlap the parent or something...?

Comment: From a usability point of view, I do now know how desirable that would be.